# Is there any source of getting the entire world - country - state - county(district) boundaries

Tags: html, google-maps, geocode

Anyone knows any source of getting the entire world - country - state - county(district) boundaries. I got the us state - county boundaries from here:
[US State - county boundaries](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-kml.html). Likewise, is there any site where I can get all countries state county boundaries.

I got a [source](http://www.gadm.org), but there is no naming for each boundaries. There the entire world is splits into boundaries, but there is no information regarding which state, and what is the county/district name and all.

Thanks

Comment: You could try http://www.gadm.org/

Comment: Thanks man. That i have already gone through, But I need the boundaries with the assigned state, county or district names

Comment: 1. Please add that "requirement" to your question. 2. Why do you believe that information isn't included in that data? 3. Please give some indication of what you have done previously for research.